# Simulating packets coming in on an interface in Linux

Tags: linux, sockets, interface, packet

On Linux, how do I simulate a case of a packet coming IN on an interface? If I open a socket to that interface, and write to that socket, it means the packet is going OUT on that interface, right?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If the interface has an ip address, try opening a socket with that ip as the destination, then writing to that socket.